# Mysql importing a csv file over 5 GB but not importing?

Tags: mysql, import

I'm trying to import a csv file that is over 5 GB into mysql in a created table but it isn't importing despise showing success message:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
"path/to/this/file/StockEtablissement_utf8.csv"
INTO TABLE entreprises COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'(
siren,
nic,
siret,
statutDiffusionEtablissement,
dateCreationEtablissement,
trancheEffectifsEtablissement,
anneeEffectifsEtablissement,
activitePrincipaleRegistreMetiersEtablissement,
dateDernierTraitementEtablissement,
etablissementSiege,
nombrePeriodesEtablissement,
complementAdresseEtablissement,
numeroVoieEtablissement,
indiceRepetitionEtablissement,
typeVoieEtablissement,
libelleVoieEtablissement,
codePostalEtablissement,
libelleCommuneEtablissement,
libelleCommuneEtrangerEtablissement,
distributionSpecialeEtablissement,
codeCommuneEtablissement,
codeCedexEtablissement,
libelleCedexEtablissement,
codePaysEtrangerEtablissement,
libellePaysEtrangerEtablissement,
complementAdresse2Etablissement,
numeroVoie2Etablissement,
indiceRepetition2Etablissement,
typeVoie2Etablissement,
libelleVoie2Etablissement,
codePostal2Etablissement,
libelleCommune2Etablissement,
libelleCommuneEtranger2Etablissement,
distributionSpeciale2Etablissement,
codeCommune2Etablissement,
codeCedex2Etablissement,
libelleCedex2Etablissement,
codePaysEtranger2Etablissement,
libellePaysEtranger2Etablissement,
dateDebut,
etatAdministratifEtablissement,
enseigne1Etablissement,
enseigne2Etablissement,
enseigne3Etablissement,
denominationUsuelleEtablissement,
activitePrincipaleEtablissement,
nomenclatureActivitePrincipaleEtablissement,
caractereEmployeurEtablissement
);
```

screenshot of the success message :[mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1pDG.png)

the mysql version is mysql-5.7.24-winx64

the csv is located here http://files.data.gouv.fr/insee-sirene/StockEtablissement_utf8.zip

Comment: The screenshot says 0 rows were inserted.

Comment: yes, indeed but there no errors and it didn't import the data from the csv file.

Comment: that would be me, unfortunately.